# sonar pull request analysis is not showing any measures or code

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-gerrit

Helllo,
we have enterirpise SQ setup on premis and it is setup to do pull request analyis with Sonar Gerrit plugin.

issues is that analysis shows no code or measures and just PASSED. is there a setting that am missing?

[image]

```
sonar.host.url=http://sonar.team.com:9000

sonar.login=${env.SONAR_TOKEN}
sonar.projectKey=Services
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true
sonar.test.inclusions=src/**/test/**/*
# Exclude test subdirectories from source scope
sonar.exclusions=src/**/test/*,src/**/test/**/*,src/**/**/*.tf
sonar.c.file.suffixes=-
sonar.cpp.file.suffixes=-
sonar.objc.file.suffixes=-
```

versions below

```
20:18:48.812 INFO: SonarScanner 4.7.0.2747
20:18:48.812 INFO: Java 11.0.14.1 Eclipse Adoptium (64-bit)
20:18:48.812 INFO: Linux 5.4.0-65-generic amd64
20:18:48.941 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
20:18:48.941 DEBUG: keyStore type is : pkcs12
20:18:53.185 INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 9.2.4
```

we are forming the paths to source like below such that only changed files are scanned for. is this the right approach? if not how should we?

```
project_files=$(git diff @ @~1 --name-only | awk '{printf "%s,", $1}')
src_file_paths=$(echo ${project_files%,})
-Dsonar.sources=${src_file_paths}`
```

on sonarqube server gui we see under code tab `No code files were found for analysis`

logs

```
Issues to be commented: 0
Issues to be involved in score calculation: 0
Review has been sent
```

Jenkinsfile

```
                        withSonarQubeEnv('sonar.team.com') {
                            sh '''
                            src/jenkins/ci/pba.sh
                            '''.stripIndent()
                        }
                        sonarToGerrit(
                            inspectionConfig: [
                                    analysisStrategy: pullRequest()
                            ],
```

```
    sonar-scanner -X \
        -Dsonar.pullrequest.key="${GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER}-${GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER}" \
        -Dsonar.pullrequest.base="${GERRIT_BRANCH}" \
        -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch="${GERRIT_REFSPEC}" \
        -Dsonar.sources=${src_file_paths} \
        -Dsonar.exclusions=**/*.tf,src/**/test/*,src/**/test/**/*,src/**/**/*.tf
```

Comment: Hi, did you find the origin of the issue? I have the same sonar symptoms...

Comment: yes, i figured it. I had to specify `-Dsonar.inclusions=${scan_mr_files}`

Answer (score 1):

I had to specify inclusions and then code was populated on gui.

```
   -Dsonar.inclusions=${scan_mr_files} \
```

where `scan_mr_files` are the files that were changed in a commit or patchset.